# Retrieving vertex coordinates

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves, vertices

How can I retrieve the vertex coordinates of the summit of each pyramid to make a curve with quadratic Bezier in Blender 3.4.

[image]

Thanks for your help :)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be a selection by index.

You can solve this as follows:

[image]

Here I transfer with `Sample Index` the position of a point selected by index of another geometry, which I have included with `Object Info`.

Of course you have to select the index manually.

You could also use `Bounding Box`, `Attribute Statistic` or `Sample Nearest` to get useful results, but these solutions depend on what your geometry is like.

Comment: Easy and clear :D
Thank you so much